# A simple GUI for a C++ code

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am doing a computer vision project where i have to recognize the text in an image and output it. So I want to develop a simple GUI for my C++ code, where I can show the image in a frame and show the recognized text next to it in some text box. I have no previous experience in developing GUIs, but i think it shouldn't be hard since the interface is not complicated. I am using windows 8 and both eclipse and netbeans are installed. Please provide me with the steps and packages I need to download. Any references to some tutorials or code will be very appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you have tried. Asking "how do I make a GUI" is far too broad for this forum.

Comment: I guess you can use JAVA for making the GUI instead of c++. And use Java Native Interface for calling c++ code.

Comment: @Wajahat I wouldn't recommend that. Java hardly has a spectacular UI and JNI/JNA/Swig is just another layer of crud to deal with ..

Comment: Why is everyone's name `userXXXXXX`.. Confuses me badly. Would the real `userXXXXXX` please stand up ;) lol   @OP, look into QT or wxWidgets, etc.. These are GUI development kits. GTK and WinAPI are native to Linux and Windows respectively.

Comment: I was suggesting just because JAVA is easy. Or you could just make a GUI using visual studio.

Comment: SO QT is the fastest way to go?

Comment: I said look into it. Not "it's the fastest". That would be quite an opinionated response. It is quite nice though and very popular. There is a learning curve for it and setting up as with a lot of kits. Same with WinAPI.

Comment: Isn't there anything like in visual studio windows form application where you can drag the buttons, textboxes ... and add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suggest to use Qt, the cross-platform application framework.**

- [Download Qt:](http://qt-project.org/downloads)
- Drag and drop features with C++ IDE.
- Many [video tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63) are available on the web.
- Book: [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) | [pdf](http://grimaldi.univ-tln.fr/Qt/C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed.pdf)